# Mips Assembly why am I getting "operand is of incorrect type" while trying to add a float with $zero and branch on it

Tags: assembly, mips

So I am working on a program and I'm trying to branch if the number in $f12 is less then zero.  But I keep getting "operand is of incorrect type".  I have tried a few things but can't figure it out.  Note I'm still quite new to Assembly so it's probably something simple.

Here is the code that's the issue

```
   mov.d $f12, $f22
   
   add $t1, $zero, $f12
   bltz $t1, Negative
```

So I have my number loaded in $f12 and I'm trying to check if it's less then zero, if so it should branch to the Negative function.

Comment: Integer `add` needs all 3 operands to be GP-integer registers.  Your problem has nothing to do with branching, just copying data from FP to integer registers.  You can either convert to integer, or just copy the bit-pattern since 2's complement integers are also only negative if the sign-bit is set.  (That would treat `-0.0` as negative, unlike an FP `f < 0.0`.  It would also be true for `-nan`)

Comment: It's already an integer stored in $f12 so I don't understand this.

Comment: `$f12` is an FP *register*, not an integer register.  It's the register name that's the problem, not the bit-pattern stored in it.

Comment: Apparently I should have looked for a clearer duplicate since you asked a followup ([Mips Assembly converting value in $f12 to int to fix "operand is of incorrect type"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72050512)).  The key part of the one I linked was `mfc1 $a0, $f0` to copy a word from an FP register to an integer register, not just the conversion of the bit-patterns.