# Mips Assembly converting value in $f12 to int to fix "operand is of incorrect type"

Tags: assembly, mips

I was told I was getting this error because I need to convert the floating point to integer but I followed the code given and I'm now getting the error for $f12 and $f0.  Not sure what the issue is.

Here is my code.  The issue is with `la $t1, ($f12)` and `cvt.w.s $f0, $f1` How do I properly convert this so I can compare the value to zero to find out if it's negative?

```
   mov.s $f12, $f22 #store the result from otherfile
             
   LI $v0, 4
   LA $a0, msg2
   syscall
  
   li $v0, 2
   mov.d $f12, $f22
   
   
   la $t1, ($f12)
   l.s $f1, ($t1)             #f1 = $f12
   cvt.w.s $f0, $f1           #f0 = (int) $f12
   
   slt $s0, $f0, $zero
   bne $s0, $zero, Negative
```

Update:

Watched a tutorial and was able to get this code but it's still saying the la line is of incorrect type.  The floating point double is stored in $f12 though?

```
   la $t0, ($f12)
   ldc1 $f2,0($t0)  # Load double floating point number
   cvt.w.d $f2, $f2
   mfc1 $t1, $f2   # Take the integer in FP Reg and put into $t1
```

Comment: Could you explain more?  It's two linked files and $f22 was sent back from the main file which then gets moved to $f12.  So it's not saved inside any label.

Comment: Do you see that `mov.d` instruction you have above?  That's an example how you might copy data between two floating point registers.

Comment: Registers do not have addresses so you can't take the address of a register (they don't live in memory; they are separate storage from memory).  Floating point registers hold floating point values, and cannot be used to as pointers to access memory.

Comment: Okay so what I really need to do is convert $f12 to an integer.  I shouldn't have to load an address?

Comment: Just made an update with code.

Comment: What/whose address would be involved?

Comment: I believe I actually figured it out.  Went to my linked file and made the label globl so I could call it.  Now it's working, isn't comparing the value correctly to zero and branching but what's a separate issue.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ErikEidt What if I declared something like number: .word 0 how would I store $f12 into that .word to call upon it?

Comment: Give the data a label and say `s.s $f12, label`.  Should use `.float` instead of `.word`, but that will work.  (More important when the data is of type double.)

Comment: Integer instructions, and all addressing modes, can't use `$f` registers.  But you don't need any integer instructions/registers to branch on an FP condition; you can use `c.lt.s $f12, $f0` (after setting `$f0` to 0) to compare for less-than https://godbolt.org/z/M97cbf68f .  Or with MIPS32r6 `cmp.lt.s  $f0,$f0,$f12` / `bc1nez  $f0, target`